# Publishing and subscribing to a topic in different threads

Tags: ros, topic, threads, subscribe, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I was just curious about this, before I actually sit for coding.

Suppose I have a thread in which I am publishing to a topic. Then, can I subscribe
to that same topic from some different thread?

I am really sorry if this question is too trivial. I just don't want to end up
writing code for nothing :)

All help is appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43437/publishing-and-subscribing-to-a-topic-in-different-threads/) by [Nishant](https://answers.ros.org/users/2440/nishant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2012-09-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can do this.

In fact, if you're in c++, if you use the [shared_ptr signatures](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Intraprocess_Publishing) in your code, you will even skip the serialization/deserialization step.

Do note, however, that by default roscpp only uses a single thread if you use `ros::spin()` or `ros::spinOnce()`.

For more info on roscpp threading models and how to use multiple threads with roscpp, see [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning#Multi-threaded_Spinning).

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4